# Getting exception while fetching data from cloudant DB using selector through Java program

Tags: java, cloudant

I created documents in CloudantDB as per below structure.

```
{
  "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "_rev": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "SOCIALKEY": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "SCREEN_USER": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "TWEETS_FEED": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "LOCATION": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "CREATEDATE": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "ANALYSIS_STATUS": "N",
  "SENTIMENT_STATUS": "NA",
  "MIXED": "NA",
  "SCORE": "NA"
}
```

I am trying to retrieve all documents which matches the criteria as"ANALYSIS_STATUS"="N". I am using CloudantClient.jar to connect CloudantDB & to perform DB operation.
I have written below code to retrieve docs.

```
public List<TweetsFeed> getTweetFeed() {
        List<TweetsFeed> tweetList=new ArrayList<TweetsFeed>();
        String selector="\"selector\": {\"ANALYSIS_STATUS\" : \"N\"},\"fields\": [\"_id\",\"TWEETS_FEED\"],\"limit\": 10,\"skip\": 0";
        try{
            db = CloudantClientMgr.getDB();
            tweetList=db.findByIndex(selector,TweetsFeed.class);
            System.out.println("size==>"+tweetList.size());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tweetList;
    }
```

Below is the TweetsFeed.class structure

```
public class TweetsFeed {
    public Integer id;
    public String socialKey;
    public String screenUser;
    public String tweetsFeed;
    public String location;
    public Date createdate;
    public String analysisStatus;
......
}
```

After execution I am getting below error.

```
[err] com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 27
[err]   at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:779)
[err]   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:769)
[err]   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
[err]   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
[err]   at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.getFindByIndexBody(Database.java:1102)
[err]   at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.findByIndex(Database.java:360)
[err]   at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.findByIndex(Database.java:323)
[err]   at com.ibm.dao.CloudantDaoImpl.getTweetFeed(CloudantDaoImpl.java:254)
[err]   at com.ibm.service.SocialKeyManagerImpl.getTweetFeed(SocialKeyManagerImpl.java:78)
[err]   at com.ibm.scheduler.SentimentAnalysis.insertAnalysis(SentimentAnalysis.java:41)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[err]   at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:283)
[err]   at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:272)
[err]   at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
[err]   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
[err]   at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
[err] Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 27
[err]   at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505)
[err]   at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1386)
[err]   at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:531)
[err]   at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414)
[err]   at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:775)
[err]   ... 18 more
Size of List---->0
Data not available
```

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Which version of CloudantClient are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The `selector` string should only be the JSON for the selector.
You need to use `FindByIndexOptions` to specify the other parameters for your index query and provide that to the `findByIndex` method like this:

```
String selector="\"selector\": {\"ANALYSIS_STATUS\" : \"N\"}";
FindByIndexOptions options = new FindByIndexOptions()
            .fields("_id")
            .fields("TWEETS_FEED")
            .limit(10)
            .skip(0);

db.findByIndex(selector, TweetsFeed.class, options);
```

Comment: I tried above code but in TweetsFeed object getting null value .

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates a malformed JSON input - Selector needs to be a complete JSON format encapsulated with {} -

Try below one -

```
String selector="{\"selector\": {\"ANALYSIS_STATUS\" : \"N\"},\"fields\": [\"_id\",\"TWEETS_FEED\"],\"limit\": 10,\"skip\": 0}";
```